# How do I keep a span on the same line as an input using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I want is a `<form>` with a text `<input>` that has a `<span>` displayed inline on the right of it.

I want the `<input>` to scale to the size of the window, but the `<span>` to stay the same size but always on the **same line** as the `<input>`.

How would I do this, using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a visual explanation of

> input to scale to the size of the window, but the span to stay the same size but always on the same line as the input.

Here is an example of inline span with input

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" style="height:150px;"/>
    <span>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Span</i>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input class="col-xs-4" style="height:150px;" type="text" /> 
  <span class="col-xs-2">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Span</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Visually similar to your example, except I don't want the span to 'visually connected' to the text input. And I want it displayed on the right hand side, does that make sense? Like this: https://sketch.io/render/sk-d781b81d973c283235448b605d7977ff.jpeg

Comment: That's close, but I want the input to fill the entire horizontal space of the parent div. So when the screen is different sizes, the inputs will fill that space or at least scale to it. One more thing, I NEVER want the span to go onto the next line, or I at least want to choose when it does (based on bootstrap's col-xs).